# using Reflect.getMetadata() in angular 2.0.0-rc1?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-decorator

How can I use `Reflect.getMetadata()` in angular 2.0.0-rc1 ?

I've found definition of `Reflect` namespace in typings `ambient/es6-shim`. Should I install any package?

Comment: `Reflect` is used to handle decorators in Angular2. Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7#.anuuv22gm) by **@Thierry Templier** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am using it like this:

```
window['Reflect'].getMetadata('annotations', target);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are two parts:

- **The compilation one**. You need typings in this case. It's now part of the core-js typings.
- **The execution one**. You need to have the `Reflect.js` included into your main HTML page.

  ```
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script> <----
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  ```

Doing that you can call `Reflect.getMetadata()` within your code.

Comment: I've replaced es6-shim with core-js 2.4.0. In `typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts' and namespace `Reflect` does not have `getMetadata` thus VSC can't use it :(

Comment: I've cloned [original quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) project and still namespace `Reflect` does not have `getMetadata`